# I want to covert julian date(YYJJJ format) to any normal date format(MMDDYY) using c#. Is there any defined function for that?

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi I have julian date  string `YYJJJ` format. eg `05365`(31st dec 2005). I want to covert to `MMDDYY` format(`123105`).

Is there any defined function for that in?

Comment: what have you tried so far? `.ToShortDateString` or simply `.ToString("MMddyy")`?

Comment: Have you looked at MSDN? There's an object called `DateTime` which has a lot of helper methods such as `format()`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: the problem is I have string which is in "yyjjj" format. I dont have any julain date calender where I cant use to .ToShortDateString and other date function

Comment: format() function of DateTime class do not covert to julian date format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no `YY`, `JJJ` and `DD` formats as a [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). One solution *might* be to split your string `Year` and [`DayOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part and create a `DateTime` with [`JulianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
string s = "05365";
int year = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, 2));
// Get year part from your string
int dayofyear = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(2));
// Get day of years part from your string
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1999 + year, 12, 18, new JulianCalendar());
// Initialize a new DateTime one day before year value. 
// Added 1999 to year part because it makes 5 AD as a year if we don't.
// In our case, it is 2004/12/31
dt = dt.AddDays(dayofyear);
// Since we have a last day of one year before, we can add dayofyear to get exact date
```

I initialized this `new DateTime(..` part with 18th December because

From [Julian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)

> Consequently, the Julian calendar is currently **13** days behind the
>   Gregorian calendar; for instance, 1 January in the Julian calendar is
>   14 January in the Gregorian.

And you can format your `dt` like;

```
dt.ToString("MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) //123105
```

I honestly didn't like this way but this is the only one I can imagine as a solution.

Comment: I'm not certain if the OP is referring to a date in the julian calendar, or simply to the date format YYDDD (two digits for the number of years since 2000, three digits for the number of days in that year, hence 00001 would be 1 January, 2000). See http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/toolsJulian.php for example.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem as I was try to convert dates from BACS 18 standard to a String.  I couldn't find ready solution to this problem so I wrote this function:

```
    private String bacsDateConvert(String bacsFormatDate)
    {
        int dateYear = Convert.ToInt16(bacsFormatDate.Substring(1, 2));
        int dateDays = Convert.ToInt16(bacsFormatDate.Substring(3, 3));

        DateTime outputDate = new DateTime();
        outputDate = Convert.ToDateTime("31-12-1999");

        outputDate = outputDate.AddYears(dateYear);
        outputDate = outputDate.AddDays(dateDays);

        String outputString = outputDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");


        return outputString;
    }
```

//You may call it like this:
textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(bacsDateConvert(bacsTxnValueDate));

You also may modify it slightly and easily make it return DateTime data type if you want to.  I just needed to return a string in the above format.

Comment: Please note that the date I'm converting from is in this format bYYddd where b is blank space YY is the year and ddd is the number of day. You need to change the Substring arguments to (0,2) and (2,3) if the format you are converting from is YYddd.