# Validate YYYY/DDD string to Date

Tags: c#

Is there a way to convert a yyyy/ddd string to Date in C#?
For example 2019003 is January 3, 2019.

Also to validate if the string is yyyy/ddd format.

Kindly help

Comment: So `ddd` is the day number of the year?

Comment: I've never seen that date format before - how would you even know that `2019003` is in the month of January when there's no month in your date format?

Comment: @Ben There's 365-365 days in a year, which I assume is what DDD means in this case. OP could have done with a better example than January, of course.

Comment: OP, did you mean 2019/003 or 2019003?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Ah, I see, that makes sense now!    I agree, an example using a different month would be clearer

Comment: One way would be to parse into `int`, then `% 1000` to get the "days" and `/ 1000` to get the year. And then `new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(days-1)`... there probably isn't a "built-in" way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Also, there is no way to distinguish if for example `2019123` is of format `yyyyddd` or of format `yyyyMdd` (or `yyyyMMd` for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a `TryParse` method like this:

```
public static bool TryParseSpecialDate(string dateString, out DateTime parsedDate)
{
    parsedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    // parse yyyy/DDD into 2 separate capture groups
    var match = Regex.Match(dateString ?? string.Empty, @"^(\d{4})/(\d{3})$");
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a date for yyyy/01/01
    var yearDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value), 1, 1);
    var dayOfYear = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
    if (dayOfYear < 1 || dayOfYear > 366)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Add the required number of days
    var result = yearDate.AddDays(dayOfYear - 1);
    // Check that it's the same year (so that 2019/888 won't work, or 366 in a non leap year)
    if (result.Year != yearDate.Year)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the date and return it
    parsedDate = result;
    return true;
}
```

I've used regex (I didn't need to but it seemed easier, feel free to replace it with string operations instead). This then starts from January in the desired year, and adds the number of days to it.

Usage:

```
bool success = DateTimeHelpers.TryParseSpecialDate("2019/354", out tmp);
```

Output will be 2019/12/20

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/WGAQ79951)

Comment: You should also check if dayOfYear > 0 :) Then the answer will be complete :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's method to achieve that:

```
public DateTime ParseDateString(string strDt)
{
    // validate string, pattern explanation:
    // \d - match sigle digit
    // ^ - match beginning of a string
    // $ - match end of a string
    // /? - match zero or one /
    if(! Regex.Match(strDt, @"^\d\d\d\d/?\d\d\d$").Success)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
    // get rid of a optional /
    strDt = strDt.Replace("/", "");
    var days = int.Parse(dt.Substring(4));
    var year = int.Parse(dt.Substring(0, 4));

    var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    return date.AddDays(days - 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't really validate it - 2/0/1/9/9/9/9 would still count as valid, but I doubt that the OP would expect it to be.

Comment: This still treats 2019/999 as a valid date though.

Comment: @JonSkeet While you are right, OP didn't say how to hadnle that. So we can make endless assumptions, i.e. what in case of 0000000, etc...

Comment: Given that the title includes "validate" I think it's reasonable to expect that it should only accept valid dates. 0000/000 should be invalid as well I suspect - and even 2019/000. To put it another way: if someone asked for a yyyy-MM-dd validator, would you think it okay to provide a solution that treated 9999-99-99 as valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
string julianDate = "2019003";
int year = Convert.ToInt32(julianDate.Substring(0, 4));

int dayOfYear = Convert.ToInt32(julianDate.Substring(4));

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year-1, 12, 18, new JulianCalendar());
dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(dayOfYear);
```

This should return the desired date.

Reference:

[I want to covert julian date(YYJJJ format) to any normal date format(MMDDYY) using c#. Is there any defined function for that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602331/i-want-to-covert-julian-dateyyjjj-format-to-any-normal-date-formatmmddyy-usi)